# How to notify exception to client after HTTP code is returned

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, influxdb

I use Java and Spring framework to create, inside a REST controller class, a method bound to GET requests.

However, the result returned by this method is sent as a stream which is fed asynchronously by another service (using InfluxDB).

Therefore, it immediately returns code 200 to the client, even though a timeout or any exception can occur afterwards.

I would like to notify the client about this.

```
/**
 * InfluxDB service
 */
@Inject
InfluxDBService influxDBService;

/**
 * @return CSV file containing the data
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/dump", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/csv")
public @ResponseBody void getDump(
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value = "app", required = false) String appFilter,
        @RequestParam(value = "context", required = false) String contextFilter,
        @RequestParam(value = "path", required = false) String pathRegex
        ) throws DataAnalysisException {

    [...]

    InputStream dump = influxDBService.dump( ... filters after treatment ...);

    response.setContentType("application/csv");

    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    String fileName = "influxdb-dump_" + currentTime + ".csv";

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
    try {
        FileCopyUtils.copy(dump, response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new DataAnalysisException("Could not get output from request results", e);
    }
}
```

In the dump() method, an OkHttpClient creates a remote connection to an InfluxDB server and returns an InputStream of data. This client has a default timeout of 10 seconds.

If there is not too much data, everything works fine and the client downloads a CSV with correct data.

But if the InfluxDB server doesn't answer in time (too much data), **then an empty CSV file is downloaded, even though HTTP code 200 is returned.**

Thing is, when I debug, it goes through the FileCopyUtils.copy line which returns 200, **but after 10 seconds it goes through the "throw new DataAnalysisException" catch-block. But at this time, client has already downloaded an empty CSV and got code 200.**

DataAnalysisException is a custom exception returning HTTP code 500.

My question is : **after the timeout, is there a way to notify the client that we actually had an issue even though he got 200 ?** That could help me build an error page to notify him.

Thanks to you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Instead of FileCopyUtils.copy, I used StreamUtils.copy, which is basically the same thing, except it doesn't automatically close the input and output streams.

Then, in a catch clause, I do response.reset() then response.sendError(code, "msg"), and throw an exception.

And in a finally clause, I manually close both input and output streams.

Therefore, the CSV headers and remaining data are cleared, and when the streams close it doesn't tell the browser to download a CSV file.

Don't hesitate to contact me if you need more info or precise code.